# Generate a number and check if it is already in a ArrayList

Tags: java, random, arraylist, numbers

I would like to generate 10 random numbers. But before I add a number to the ArrayList, I need to check if my Arraylist already contains a number which is in the range between `randomNumber - 50` and `randomNumber + 50`.

For example, if random number is 120 :
120-50=70
120+50=170

If the ArrayList contains a number between 70 and 170, I will not add it to my ArrayList and run again the cycle...

What is wrong with my code?

```
package ee.tlu;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Testing {
    public Testing() {
        List < Integer > numbers = new ArrayList < > ();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number = rand.nextInt(5000);
        int n = 0;
        boolean listis = false;
        numbers.add(number);
        while (n < 10) {
            number = rand.nextInt(5000);
            for (int k = number - 50; k < number + 50; k++) {
                if (numbers.contains(k)) {
                    listis = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!listis) {
                numbers.add(number);
                n += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem. What's the expected result and what the actual result.

Comment: What sort of error occurs?

Comment: Expected result is a list of 10 random number which are in array and between two numbers the distance is at least 50 units. For example 5, 560, 4444, 140, 219, 300, 1000, 390, 900, 2555. But this one is bad one: 5, 40, 100, 101, 300, 300, 500, 600, 7, 45. Martze, Eclipse sometimes runs and sometimes not...

Comment: @Bubletan has the correct answer. In addition to that, you should consider looping on `numbers` instead of looping on all integers between `number - 50` and `number + 50`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare `listis` before you start the while-loop. It's never reset once it has been set to true. Move it inside the loop.

Also, you never check the `number + 50` as you are having `<` instead of `<=` in your for-loop.

```
while (n < 10) {
    boolean listis = false;
    number = rand.nextInt(5000);
    for (int k = number - 50; k <= number + 50; k++) {
        if (numbers.contains(k)) {
            listis = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!listis) {
        numbers.add(number);
        n += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's the only problem, but you should reset your `listis` flag in each iteration of the while loop :

```
    while (n < 10) {
        listis = false; // added
        number = rand.nextInt(5000);
        for (int k = number - 50; k < number + 50; k++) {
            if (numbers.contains(k)) {
                listis = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!listis) {
            numbers.add(number);
            n += 1;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, the first time you find a number that shouldn't be added, you will stop adding any numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> I would do this recursively. I haven't tested the below code, just a quick mockup on notepad. But hopefully this will help.

```
public class Testing {

    public List < Integer > numbers = new ArrayList < > ();

    public Testing() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int number = rand.nextInt(5000);

        // initial number in arraylist
        numbers.add(number);

        // add 9 more numbers to arraylist
        addNumbers(9);

        System.out.println(numbers);
    }

    public void addNumber(int amountLeft){
        int newNumber = rand.nextInt(5000);

        if(isValidNumberToAdd(newNumber))
        {
            numbers.add(newNumber);
        }

        if(amountLeft == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        addNumber(amountLeft--);
    }

    public boolean isValidNumberToAdd(int newNumber)
    {
        Iterator<int> numbersIterator = numbers.iterator();
        while (numbersIterator.hasNext()) {
            int number = numbersIterator.next();
            if(newNumber > number - 50 && newNumber < number + 50)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Set instead of List. Sets guarantee that:
[Adding new element to the set works only if new element is not already present in the set.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E))